# What is the best algorithm to model credit default score for gamification?

Tags: predictive-models, missing-data, boosting

**Goal:**

I have a situation that I want to create a model to predict credit default that could handle any missing data for any feature, although my observations don't have any missing data for any feature.

The goal here is to create this model for gamification purposes - the more information people give me, the more precise the prediction would be.

**The current scenario:**

- I have 3 years of data, ~30 features and 1 variable to be predicted (a binary variable for the credit default event)
- As said, I don't have any missing data for any feature or the variable to be predicted
- Despite being capable to handle missing data, I don't want to make the model worse on predictions for observations with no missing data - it should predict as well as it had been trained without missing data.

Any thoughts about good algorithms to handle this situation for "missing data"?

Comment: This is unclear. Why do you expect missing data in future? Any ideas which features could be missing? Why?

Comment: The first step in dealing with missing data problems is to determine why the data are missing, and if it can be classified as MCAR, MAR, or NMAR. I would suspect that people will be more likely to supply information that makes them look good and less likely to specify information showing they're a risk. That would imply the data is NMAR. That makes this a difficult problem to solve.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen the future missing data is something planned. Suppose you are a person that needs money and my lending platform allows you to give as many information about you as you want (each question will be asked sequentially). The more fields you fill or the more information you allow me to consult, the more precise I can evaluate your risk and the more precise I can be with your quote.

This way I can price the risk of not having some data about you. Consequently, with it, I can create incentive you to give me more information in exchange for a more accurate quote and credit limit.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen complementing: this way I would not lost borrowers that don't want to provide all the information to me, because I would allow them to stop filling the loan form on the step/field that they fill comfortable, in exchange of having a worse and/or less accurate quote.

Just let me know if I was clear enough.

The mechanics is a mix of behavior economics, microeconomics and risk pricing, applied to digital platforms.

Comment: @DavidLukeThiessen not necessarily people would provide this information to me by  "self-providing" it. For example, this information could be an opt-in or a permission to consult their data on an external source (like consult their bank statement through an authorization).

But you are right, we could have some adversarial selection and the data could be NMAR - although I think this could be also quantified in terms of risks after some cycles of lending and re-training.

Comment: @DavidLukeThiessen I was thinking about training different tree models - that for each training set I would remove a feature or more. After that I would have a set of tree models. The problem here is that for all combinations of features, this would give me 30! tree models - not even close to something feasible.

Do you have any suggestion where I can start from?

Comment: I don't have any specific suggestions, but this sounds like a type of "bucket of models" approach. I don't have any references for that, but maybe you'll have better luck searching for something like that term.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidLukeThiessen, I will